# java flashing object with stable frequency

Tags: java, swing, frequency

All the other questions I found seem to be related to "flicker-free" whereas I actually want a flicker...

I am trying to build a small app that shows objects blinking at a given frequency.

Below is a small workable example of what I am trying to do. Currently I flicker the object via a scheduled Task that is executed with a given frequency. Within this task I paint the object, wait for half the time and then delete it. That should give me a object that is blinking with the given frequency.

However I found that even at frequencies as low as 4Hz the blinking isn't stable anymore. I think this is due to the fact that Java does not guarantee to paint the screen when asked to but that it is allowed to pull certain paint tasks together into one. I am not sure but I think I read something like this.

My question is: How can I make a stably blinking object with frequencies up to the half the screen refreshing rate?

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private final int FlashFreqHz = 4;
private java.util.Timer timer;
/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    startFlashing();
}
private class FlashingTask extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int w=jPanel1.getWidth();
        int h=jPanel1.getHeight();
        try {
            jPanel1.getGraphics().fillRect(10, 10, w/2, h/2);
            Thread.sleep((1000/FlashFreqHz)/2);
            jPanel1.getGraphics().clearRect(10, 10, w/2, h/2);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public void startFlashing() {
    if(timer!=null) stopFlashing(); //  running, must stop to get new position correct

    timer = new java.util.Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new FlashingTask(), 0, 1000/FlashFreqHz); // 40 ms delay
}
public void stopFlashing() {
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
        jPanel1.repaint();
    }
}
```

---

Just to check, here is my 'corrected' code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener{
private final int FlashFreqHz = 60;
private final Timer timer;
private boolean Flash = false;
FlashFrame FlashPanel;
/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    FlashPanel = new FlashFrame();
    setContentPane(FlashPanel);
    timer = new Timer(1000/FlashFreqHz,this);
    timer.start(); 

}
class FlashFrame extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);       
        if(Flash) {
            g.fillRect(10, 10, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2); 
        } else {
            g.clearRect(10, 10, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2); 
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    FlashPanel.repaint();
    Flash = !Flash;
}
```

Does this look any better to you?

Also the question I began with remains. Although the frequency is much much more stable then with my 'sleep' method there still is some notable instability, especially at higher frequencies.

Is there anything that can be done about that?

Comment: Thread.sleep() is an inherently unstable way to time things like that, not only is it platform dependent on how it acts, if the OS decides to sleep the jvm thread for a second, the thread.sleep() task won't see that

Comment: Using getGraphics is not how custom painting is done. Using Java.util.Timer violates the single thread rules of Swing. Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Your updated code is fine. If you are still noticing instability (at what frequencies by the way?) it may be unrelated to the Swing painting mechanism. My experience is Swing is capable of processing thousands of events per second so asynchronous repaints are capable of a very high frame rate (much greater than monitor refresh) when given a simple painting task.

Comment: Actually I thought of one thing you could try which is to call [`setCoalesce(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setCoalesce%28boolean%29) on the Timer. `javax.swing.Timer` coalesces the action events by default. Though I do not think it will really make much of a difference, my bet is still that you are trying frequencies that are higher than the monitor refresh rate (impossible to display no matter what you do).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I will test the 'Coalesce' idea, thanks for that. The monitor refresh rate is 60Hz and even at 20Hz flickering rate one starts to see small discontinuities. As I said before it is MUCH better now and probably acceptable, I was just wondering if it could be improved further easily. Of course increasing the flickering rate above 60Hz yields bogus results :D

Comment: In `actionPerformed`, first update the value of `Flash`, then call repaint. Use double buffering (offscreen image) for better results.